# OpenFB ionic not working on android

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

I am doing a project with Ionic and I want to add the posibility to post a message on facebook. I choose to use OpenFB to do so, and when I am testing with my browser it's working fine. I can login and put a message on my wall. But when I am trying with android I can still login but when I am trying to post something I get an error. `GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=CAAYK...DJE 404 (Not Found)`
This is really strange because the login is ok (so I have access to internet) but calling the graph api is not. I tried to use this url on a browser and I can get the response, so the token is valid. I was thinking about the whitelist in the facebook dev panel but I already followed this tutorial https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try whitelisting your GET request with the cordova-whitelist-plugin:

[Cordova Whitelist Plugin](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist)